# DC-input motherboard How does HDD get power? --- ASRock H81TM-ITX

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, power-supply, power

This may be quite a simple question, but I do not know much of anything when it comes to building motherboards, voltages, wattages, and power.

I am looking at this board - ASRock H81TM-ITX ([http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157532&cm_re=H81TM-ITX_R2.0-*-13-157-532-*-Product](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157532&cm_re=H81TM-ITX_R2.0-_-13-157-532-_-Product))

I have noticed that it would be able to take a 19V DC-in power adapter as a power source instead of sticking a power supply in the build. My question is, what do the other components that have separate power connectors do in this case?

In particular, a regular SATA 6gb/s like this one - http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148820

I assumed that all the components would somehow be powered by the DC power supplied to the board. When I thought about how to connect those components to receive that power though, I became a bit confused.

If someone could clear my confusion on how to properly supply power, and how to properly configure components (or which to look for specifically) for this board - I would be so appreciative.

Thank you!

Comment: I see no mention of that feature.  Please provide the link to the manual

Comment: Under "Features" - "1 x DC-In Jack (Compatible with 19V power adapter)" ---

[The Manual](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H81TM-ITX%20R2.0/?cat=Manual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the section named `Internal I/O Connectors` is says `1 x SATA Power Connector`. I'd say that'd do it.  You can keep chaining those while the power holds out.

BTW, these style of boards are generally really susceptible to damage from power fluctuations. We use them at work because we get them cheap enough that we can treat them as disposable but they are really bad.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for that insight! By these style, do you mean boards that support DC-IN or mini-itx boards that are targeted for small machines?

Comment: They are one in the same but, yes, you cannot replace a $75 power supply with a $2 wall wart and expect to have the same quality.

Comment: Ah, my thought was that I could buy something like a beefy HP laptop AC Adapter and use that to power the system. (newline formatting be damned)
Is your suggestion however, to simply use a PSU instead of the DC-IN power adapter? (newline formatting be damned)
I feel like it would be easier to replace a DC-IN power adapter than have to open up the case, replace PSU, reconnect power connectors, etc.

Comment: A wall wart will work but don't expect a long life out of the PC if that's what you're using. I'm not worried about the power adapter; it is the PC that is at risk. A PC PSU is actually a very sophisticated power conditioner and a wall wart is not in the same class; even a laptop power supply.

Comment: I see. So to clarify my understanding - a wall wart is an AC Adapter, and wall wart's are not as sophisticated as a PC PSU. This makes wall wart's a poor choice and shortens the life of a PC. You recommend buying a PC PSU for this board. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if at all possible. I don't know which case you're looking at for it though and they tend to be very tight in this class of PC.

Comment: My only question to you then is, if wall warts are harmful to the life of a PC - what about laptops then? All laptop's use wall warts, and laptop's have been around for ages and they work fine. Wouldn't the same problem apply to a laptop PC? They use similar boards, and DC-IN

Comment: The battery protects the main board from power spikes. It works just like a giant capacitor (like the one in a PSU).

Comment: I see, so the difference here is that a PC would not have a battery like a laptop to protect itself...would you be able to recommend a High Quality well-known-brand 200W~ PSU?

Comment: Sorry but you're going to want one of those little PSU for that form factor. I really have no experience buying those. For my desktop, I've been happy with my Corsair PSU.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the tradeoff. I looked around for 200W PSU's and they all look generic, I cannot find a corsair, cooler master, antec, or any well known PSU at 200W. That is very dangerous though, PSU is so important, if I get a low-quality PSU it may be worse than just using DC-IN with a very good laptop AC adapter. Don't you think so?

Answer (score 1):

There is an onboard DC to DC converter. It electronically coverts the 19 VDC external power to the various voltages required by the CPU and other components.

That particular device is the reason that these small systems should never be equipped with higher than specified TDP CPUs. The converter has a total current rating, seldom passed on to the end user. Exceeding its max rating can burn it out. No, switching to a higher rated external 19 VDC supply won't help.

The connector number 8 mentioned above is the SATA power connector. It provides power to the SATA drive(s). It is NOT for an external power source.

Hooking wall warts or huge external supplies to the board is pretty much guaranteed to smoke it.